# Unable to attach to machine 'machine name' - Visual Studio 2003

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I get the following error: `Unable to attach to machine 'machine name'` when running my project in `debug mode` with visual studio 2003.

I have not find this error/solution anywhere on google or stackoverflow, this is why I am asking here. I'm not even sure what is causing it, I haven't made any changes to the **project's Property** or any code.

**Additional Info:**

1. Debug mode worked fine before.
2. No issue with release mode.

Any hints will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was somehow related to **ClearCase** version Control. Making a new view in **ClearCase** solved the problem.